# Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted. How do I remove this error?

Tags: c

Following error occurs during execution of following code after `vertices = vert(i,n,m,arr);` line in`main()`.

> `a.out: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion (old_top == initial_top
>   (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsignProgram received signal SIGABRT,
>   Aborted.use (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1))
>   =__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51`

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int check(int j, int n, int m, int *subset, int arr[m][2]){
    int i,k;
    if(subset[arr[j][0]]==1||subset[arr[j][1]]==1){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}



int *binary_num(int i,int m,int n){
    int j,k;
    int *binary=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        if(i%2==1){
            binary[j]=1;
        }
        else
            binary[j]=0;
        i=i/2;
    }
    return binary;
}

int valid_subset(int i,int m, int n, int *subset, int arr[m][2]){
    int *binary = binary_num(i,m,n);
    int j,k;
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        if(binary[j]==1){
            if(check(j,n,m,subset,arr)==0)
                return 0;
            else{
                subset[arr[j][0]]=1;
                subset[arr[j][1]]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}



int *vert(int i,int n,int m, int arr[m][2]){
    int *binary = binary_num(i,m,n);
    int *vertices = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(binary[j]==1){
            vertices[arr[j][0]]=1;
            vertices[arr[j][1]]=1;
        }
    }
    return vertices;
}


int main() {
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    int i,j,k,tmp1,tmp2,max_count=0;
    int arr[m][2];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&tmp1,&tmp2);
        arr[i][0]=tmp1;
        arr[i][1]=tmp2;
    }
    int valid;
    int *vertices;
    int *binary;
    int max_i;
    int max_match;
    int subset[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        subset[i]=0;
    }
    double power = pow(2,n);
    for(i=0;i<power;i++){
        valid=valid_subset(i,m,n,subset,arr);
        if(valid==1){
            vertices = vert(i,n,m,arr);
            for(j=0,max_match=0;j<n;j++){
               if(vertices[j]==1){
                    max_match++;
               }
            }
        }
        if(max_match>max_count){
            max_count=max_match;
            max_i = i;
        }
    }
    binary = binary_num(max_i,m,n);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf("yes\n");
        if(binary[i]==1){
            printf("%d %d\n",arr[i][0],arr[i][1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running your code through Valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: What value are you entering for `n`? This `int i; double power = pow(2,n); for(i=0;i<power;i++){ ... }` will only work for small values of `n`. The code does no error checking, nor check of `n` value.

Comment: You should either run valgrind or a debugger. You allocate a lot of memory using some complicated size calculations, based on `m` and `n` inputs. You need to make sure that all your writes and reads are within legal ranges.